# Watching and tracking state changes with Vuex inside child components

Tags: vue.js, vuex

This is more a "which method should I use" question, rather than a how to.

I have the following in my `Vuex.Store()` instance:

`store.js`:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    acceptedTermsAndConditions: false
  },
})
```

From various components I'm emitting an event which sets `this.$store.state.acceptedTermsAndConditions` to `true` or `false`, dependent on different User inputs.

However, in my component I would set the checked value of a "Accepts T&Cs" checkbox to this value, something like this:

`components/Component.Vue`:

```
data () {
    return {
        form: {
            checkboxTermsAndConditions: this.$store.state.acceptedTermsAndConditions
        }
    }
}
```

I'm just not sure what method handles this? Does a solution require a `getter`? If not, what is the best way to watch for state changes and set data values accordingly?

Comment: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper

Comment: Thanks @Phil - think there's enough here to answer my own question, looks like it needs a `get()`, `set()` within `computed`...?

Comment: Only needs a `set` if you want to actually **commit** a **mutation** from your component. See https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#committing-mutations-in-components

Comment: Yeh, for 100% consistency...you can unset from the form itself.

Comment: Hi Phil, cli is returning syntax errors from the page you linked to, doesn't seemed to have helped...

Comment: Without any details of the code you've added or these errors, nobody can help any further

Comment: Hi @Phil - no problem. I wasn’t really looking for a link to docs as I can read them. I wanted to know what method was best. I’m going to store a lot of my data in the ... store. I think that’s easiest! :)

Comment: Then your question is off-topic as any answers will be _primarily opinion based_. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Noted. Thanks for your input! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the checkbox state based on the stored value, you should use the computed object and the mapGetters helper function in your component:

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper

```
computed: {
...mapGetters(['acceptedTermsAndConditions'])
}
```

Like this, the value will be accessible in your component. If you want to do the contrary (refresh the store based on the checkbox value), you should create a mutation in your store and you should use this in your component:

```
methods: {
...mapMutations(['setTACcheckbox'])
}
```

This way, inside your component you can refresh the store value with this.setTACcheckbox(value).